# ¿Cómo se puede enviar una petición oculta a través de Java?

Tags: java, http, requests

¡Hola a todos! Estoy trabajando con un código en **Java** el cual necesita que **no se vea reflejado** en receptores de tráfico HTTP/HTTPS. El problema es que mi aplicación al enviar la petición, se ve reflejada en un receptor de tráfico (utilizo HTTPDebugger) y el problema es que en la URL se utilizan **tokens e IDs** privados.

Hasta el momento creí que no se podía "ocultar" o que esa petición no se vea reflejada, hasta que me topé con la **API de Telegram**. Al ejecutar el mismo código que yo utilizo para enviar una petición hacia mi servidor, el código de Telegram (de un bot con ID y token) **evita** los receptores de tráfico, **haciendo que no se exponga dichos argumentos**.

Entonces, pienso que **si se puede hacer** pero... ¿de qué manera? Adjunto los códigos de ambas peticiones, tanto de la API de Telegram como mi código (aunque se asimilan). Tengo el pensamiento que es por la **encriptación SSL** o algo parecido pero no encuentro por ningún lado alguna respuesta al respecto. ¡Gracias a todos!

Código de petición utilizando la API de Telegram:

```
    public static void Request()
    {
      String urlString = "https://api.telegram.org/bot%s/sendMessage?chat_id=%s&text=%s&parse_mode=html";
      String apiToken = "TOKEN";
      String chatId = "ID";
      String text = "Texto de ejemplo.";
      
      urlString = String.format(urlString, new Object[] { apiToken, chatId, text });
      try
      {
        URL url = new URL(urlString);
        URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
        BufferedInputStream localBufferedInputStream = new BufferedInputStream(conn.getInputStream());
        System.out.println("Telegram enviado con éxito.");
      }
      catch (IOException e)
      {
       System.out.println("Error:" + e);
      }
    }
```

Código de petición utilizando mi servidor:

```
    public static void Request2()
    {
        String ip = "SERVER IP"; /* Ejemplo */
        String token = "TOKEN";
        String argumento = "Argumento";
        String urlString = "http://" + ip + "/api/token?=" + token + "&arg=" + argumento;

  /* urlString = String.format(urlString, new Object[] { }); (No lo utilizo a diferencia del código anterior)*/
      try
      {
        URL url = new URL(urlString);
        URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
        BufferedInputStream localBufferedInputStream = new BufferedInputStream(conn.getInputStream());
        System.out.println("Servidor enviado con éxito.");

      }
      catch (IOException e)
      {
       System.out.println("Error Server: " + e);
      }
    }
```

Adjunto imágenes donde se muestran la ejecución del código correctamente y el tráfico de mi red (incluyendo la recepción de la IP):

[image: Imagen de ejecución correcta.]

[image: Imagen del programa HTTPDebugger.]

¡Gracias a todos! Me ayudarían mucho si aportan a mis dudas.

Comment: Los datos en realidad no se ocultan se encriptan para evitar que información sensible puede ser leida.

Comment: Hola, entiendo esa parte y por eso lo aclaré pero estoy buscando la manera de hacerlo, y resolver mi duda de si esto sucede por el SSL o realmente es por otra cosa. Saludos.